# Event when list has changed

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, eventhandler

i have an event which get fired whenever the items of my list change and when this event is fired i call a method to work with this list. When there are 5 new items in the list my method gets called 5 times, foreach new element but I only need to handle the last event. how can i solve this?

```
MyObject.ListItemsChanged += RefreshElementsInUI;
```

then in the method:

```
private void RefreshElementsInUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    var listItems = getElementsForCommunication(communication);
    ClearElementsInUi();
    foreach ( var element in listItems ) 
         addElementToMyControl(element);
}
```

the ListItemsChanged Event gets fired 5 times if there are 5 new Items in my Communication but i only need the last event because i do not have to do the same work about 5 times

hope this will help

Comment: providing some code would be _really_ helpful

Comment: How are you adding to the list now? How are you raising the events? Tell us more about your code before we can help.

Comment: added some of my code

Comment: You have to implement `BeginUpdate()`/`EndUpdate()` schema, as it's done in many collection-based controls, to postpone control redraw until `EndUpdate()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you've implemented IBindingList or are using BindingList. I recommend deriving from [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) and defining [OnCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654934.aspx). Batch mode isn't builtin to any event driven .NET collections (BindingList, ObservableCollection), but it isn't hard to implement your own collection by deriving from ObservableCollection, and then writing a batch method AddRange().

```
public class MegaList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
  // Initialize new instance of Gyrasoft.Common.MegaList<T> with elements from collection. 
  public MegaList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
     : base(collection) { }

  /// Adds the elements of specified collection in batch mode, fire event once after 
  public MegaList<T> AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
  {
     foreach (var i in collection)
        Items.Add(i);

     OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
     return this;
  }
}
```